# Neo4J setting a relationship ratio based matching relationships

Tags: neo4j, relationships

I am working on building a flow model within Neo4j and looking to initially weight all edges as a proportion of the total relationships e.g.

Node A -r1-> Node B, Node A -r2-> Node C, Node A -r3-> Node D

Using the above relationships the weight(ratio) of r1,r2 and r3 would be 1/3. I am able to work out the total inbound edges:

`MATCH (n)<-[r:RTYPE]-m-[r2:RTYPE]->o return n,r,count(r2)`

However when I try:

`MATCH (n)<-[r:RTYPE]-m-[r2:RTYPE]->o SET r.Ration = 1/count(r2)`

I get a Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax.

Any / all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
MATCH (n)<-[r:RTYPE]-m-[r2:RTYPE]->o
WITH r, count(r2) as r2count
SET r.Ration = 1/r2count
```

(move the aggregate function into WITH)

Comment: thanks this works. I had to convert it to a float otherwise it did integer division so ended up with: MATCH (n)<-[r:SYMPTOMTREE]-m-[r2:SYMPTOMTREE]->o
WITH r, 1.0/(count(r2)+1.0)*1.0 as r2count
SET r.Ratio = r2count